# AltBeacon setBluetoothAddress and setBluetoothName

Tags: android, altbeacon

I'm attempting to transmit as a beacon an Android phone using the altbeacon library as described [here](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/beacon-transmitter.html). I am trying to set some parameters using the following methods:

```
setServiceUuid(0xfeaa)
setBluetoothAddress("31:14:15:92:65:35")
setBluetoothName("MyBeacon")
```

When the beacon is interpreted on another Android device in the RangeNotifier listener method, didRangeBeaconsInRegion, the beacon doesn't have these parameters set. (eg. getServiceUuid is -1 and the BT address and name are each null).

I'm using the following beacon layout in the parser for the transmitting application and in the scanning application:

```
m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25
```

I don't know what this means though; I wonder if I need to change it.

Anyone have an idea how to make the bluetooth address, name etc. be accessible in the beacon that is scanned on the receiving device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some fields in the `Beacon` class are only used when detecting beacons and do not affect transmissions.  You have found three of these exact fields.  Here is an explanation of each and why they work this way:

- **BluetoothAddress**:  this is a fixed six byte unique address built into the Bluetooth chip on your phone.  When sending packets (beacon advertisements or otherwise), the chip always uses the same address.  You cannot change it.  This is by just the way Bluetooth works.
- **BluetoothName**: this is the friendly name of your phone visible to other Bluetooth scanners.  Changing this name affects not just beacon transmissions but all Bluetooth operations on the phone.  For this reason, the library's `BeaconTransmitter` does not change this name.  You can do so youself, however, by calling the `setName` method on Android's `BluetoothAdapter` class.  See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html).
- **ServiceUUID**: This field applies only to certain beacon formats such as Eddystone, which are based on 16-bit GATT Service UUIDs.  For other beacon formats (AltBeacon, iBeacon), this value is -1 as you have seen.  The ServiceUUID is actually defined in the `BeaconParser` layout expression.  In the Beacon class you can read it, but writing to it has no effect.  You generally do not need to worry about this field, and certainly not for the AltBeacon layout shown in the question, because it is not used for that format.

Comment: Thank you David. I will try to set the BluetoothName when it is null on the device (as I am seeing in the Beacon). I suppose I won't need to filter the devices when ranging by beacon type code or service uuid.

Comment: I just took a look and my adapter (bluetoothManager.getAdapter()) on my phone and the name is set (as I would expect "Julius's Nexus 6P") and the address is set to 02:00:00:00:00:00. I'm unsure now where the adapter's details are being set.

The Beacon object that is discovered on the other device shows an address of 54:29:9A:70:6D:84 but my phone's About=>Status has a bluetooth address which starts AC:CF:85…… . However the Beacon object that is in the receiver has the same Id1 as set on the phone. Pretty confused now! Appreciate any help @davidgyoung.

Comment: Ok the 02:00:00:00:00:00 is explained as I'm on M and "Android removes programmatic access to the device’s local hardware identifier for apps using the Wi-Fi and Bluetooth APIs". So now I just need to reconcile the 54:…… and the AC:…… addresses and figure out why I still get null for the name.

Comment: Can we get bluetooth mac address in transmitter side which is display at receiver side? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60520882/altbeacon-get-macaddress-in-transmitter

Comment: Android, like iOS emits a randomized MAC in its advertisements.  This will not be the same as the physical MAC of your device reported in Settings.  There is no way to turn this off or to determine the physical MAC on the receiver side.  When scanning on another device you may or may not get the Bluetooth name.  The Bluetooth name may be provided by the scan response packet which may be emitted periodically by the transmitting device  on some Android devices.  Using Android APIs, the scan response packet containing the Bluetooth name is tacked on to the end of the scanned adv if available.